# Android Bluetooth Tethering

Tags: android, bluetooth

I am trying to Tether (Share Android phone internet connection to other device) through Bluetooth connection. And I need this to work on an unrooted phone.

I am not looking for any App. I am looking for implementation (Source code, Script etc..)

Also can we do this using PPP ? (Point to Point protocol)

Has anyone tried this before and any luck ?

I am planning to write an app for this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Sayooj Valsan

Comment: Figured out. Wrote an App which tethers internet packet using PPP over SPP. I had to create the TCP stack, emulate a DUN profile over bluetooth. When connected, open the PPP packet, extract the TCP data, use sockets connect to the host, receive packets, wrap it up back to PPP, send it back .. :) and thats alot of work !

Comment: Could you post the code as an answer please?